# What are non-scriptable objects in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-mptt

I have the following model:

```
class Performance(Event):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), default=timezone.now)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('date_modified'), auto_now=True)

class PerformanceWork(models.Model):
    perf = models.ForeignKey(Performance, related_name='perf_work', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work =  models.ForeignKey(WorkMusic, related_name='work', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class WorkMusic(MPTTModel, Work):
    ...
```

In my view.py:

```
class PerformanceView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'performances/performance.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'perf': Performance.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        })
        return context
```

In my template, I am trying to render a recursive tree with this in my template:

```
  {% for work in perf.perf_work.all %}
    {% recursetree work.work %}
    <li>
      {% if node.is_leaf_node %}
        {{ node.name_original }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
        <ul class="children">
          {{ children }}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
{% endfor %}
```

When run my app, I get the following error.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/performance/2/

Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.7.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'opus',
 'generic',
 'art_perf',
 'art_visual',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'mptt',
 'import_export',
 'googlemaps']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/howiec/Desktop/Opus/templates/performances/base.html, error at line 0
   'WorkMusic' object is not subscriptable
   1 : {% load static i18n %}
   2 : 
   3 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   4 : <html lang="en" class="{% block html_class %}{% endblock %}">
   5 : <head>
   6 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   7 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   8 :     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   9 : 
   10 :     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/performance.css' %}">


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 95, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 95, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mptt/templatetags/mptt_tags.py", line 257, in render
    roots = cache_tree_children(queryset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mptt/templatetags/mptt_tags.py", line 236, in cache_tree_children
    return get_cached_trees(queryset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mptt/utils.py", line 232, in get_cached_trees
    parent_attr = queryset[0]._mptt_meta.parent_attr

Exception Type: TypeError at /performance/2/
Exception Value: 'WorkMusic' object is not subscriptable
```

Work.work is a queryset with a WorkMusic object:

I know this is graphable when I just graph a WorkMusic object directly. I'm not sure why this break when I access the object through another model?

Comment: The error message isn't very informative, do you have any traceback that we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `recursetree` expects a collection and you're passing it an instance.

```
{% recursetree work.work %}
```

When you get this error it effectively means that you're trying to do a collection based operation on a Django model instance. Or at least that's what I've seen in my experience.

Comment: How do I fix this? When I pass a WorkMusic object directly it works.  Only when I send the WorkMusic via reference on another model does it break.

Comment: I don't think you're passing a single instance in the case that you think works. What collection/tree you need to pass into `recursetree`?

Comment: I want to pass WorkMusic into MPTT. That's why I linked it to work.work. I'm not sure it's an instance.  It' a queryset of instances.  In this case, there happens to be one instance in the query.

Comment: However, `work.work` is a single instance. It is not a query.

Answer (score 0):

To access a model object field in Django, you have to use dot notation otherwise you get a not subscriptable error.

This will throw the error:

```py
work_music_object['some_field']
```

This will not:

```py
work_music_object.some_field
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.  I pass work.work which is the correct object.